# Does changing an Android Studio project to another folder cause problems?

Tags: android, git, compiler-errors

I was working on an Android app, and decided to do an initial git commit. The project folder was on my desktop so I moved it into a newly created folder as to not make the Desktop into a git repository. The project was open in Android Studio when I moved it and made the commit, and when I went back to it it didn't work.

I closed it and reopened it and it wouldn't compile (I was a fool and didn't screen shot the error message) but then it started to work.

However, all the files in the project are in red, not the code itself, just the files that a visible in the tab on the left and the tabs at the tops of the open files. The project works but I want to get rid of the red as obviously it's an indication that something's not right.

I have to send this project for review tomorrow and I hope this won't create an issue for the recipient.

Thanks

Comment: add a picture of what you see, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are red because they have not been committed to git.

`git add .` and `git commit -m "your commit message"` should fix it.

And No it should not be a problem. I suggest you read more about git, it's a cool tool

Comment: I've commited the project twice and it says there are no changes to commit, so I don't think that is the problem. The files aren't appearing red in the terminal, they are red in Android Studio. For example all the open tabs along the top of the IDE such as MainActivity.class are written in red.

Comment: add a picture of what you see, please

Comment: When I woke up today, all the red had gone! It was related to the git commit, however I commited the project and it stayed red (until this morning). I need to figure git out. Thanks a lot for the help!